How to grab value of the nested input element's value from my own react component in isolated file?
I have "My React component" as the following:
'use client';

import styles from './range-slider.module.css'

// range input = track & thumb

export default function RangeSlider({minState, maxState} : 
    {minState: [string, Function], maxState: [string, Function]}) {
  const [min, setMin] = minState;
  const [max, setMax] = maxState;

  const handleMin = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMin(parseInt(e.target.value) < parseInt(max)? e.target.value : max);
  };

  const handleMax = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMax(parseInt(e.target.value) > parseInt(min)? e.target.value : min);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.rangeInput}>
        <div className={styles.sliderCtrl}>
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.min}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value = {min}
            onChange={handleMin}/>
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.max}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value={max}
            onChange={handleMax}/>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.inputCtrl}>
          <div className="min">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={min}
              onChange={handleMin}/>
          </div>
          <div className="max">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={max}
              onChange={handleMax}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

However, I suspect it may not be a good practice to pass the useState as a props to the RangeSlider. My question 1 is whether this is good practice and what are the suggest way to do it.
In fact, my primary purpose of mine is just to grab the value of the RangeSlider (i.e. the value of the two range input nested within it) from its parent component, I am grateful if anyone could tell me sth about it, and that's question 2.

The premise of what you are doing is absolutely fine. The syntax is arguably a little clunky. I prefer to pass specific prop names rather than just pass state directly down like this (even though the outcome would be identical). Recommend to pass 4 explicit prop names - minValue, maxValue, onChangeMin, and onChangeMax. You could arguably move the logic you have in this component of handling the value changes to the parent. You’ve made no egregious errors in doing it the way you have, however

As far as typescript goes, don’t use Function but instead define the signature of the function (value: number) => void. Again, not a huge problem, just an improvement. I suspect the downvote came from someone who thought this was an opinion based question and belonged on a code review site, as you have no specific problem you’re asking for help with

@Adam Jenkins Thanks for your detail answer and sharing selfless :). Though I finally not accepted the answer but I think I learn knowledges from your comment and answer.

Sharing State
To share state between a parent component and it's child, you want the state to "live" in the parent component, and you want to pass methods of reading and writing to that state to the child.
In short, you're approaching this the right way.
Passing State Props
Best practice is to explicitly pass min, setMin, max, and setMax as props. It helps make the purpose of each property more explicit. In practice, keeping your props flatter may help you avoid bugs. For example, if you were to ever depend on minState in a use hook (unlikely), you may find it updates more/less frequently than you'd expect, since it'd depend on the entire array as opposed to just the value element.
TypeScript
One other tip - you can explicitly type the set functions using the same types that React uses. You would use React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>> to represent the setState function for some type T.
With the above points in mind, here's how I would refactor your code:
'use client';

import styles from './range-slider.module.css'

interface RangeSliderProps {
  max: string
  setMax: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>
  min: string
  setMin: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>> 
}

export default function RangeSlider({ min, setMin, max, setMax }: RangeSliderProps) {
  const handleMin = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMin(parseInt(e.target.value) < parseInt(max) ? e.target.value : max);
  };

  const handleMax = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMax(parseInt(e.target.value) > parseInt(min) ? e.target.value : min);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.rangeInput}>
        <div className={styles.sliderCtrl}>
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.min}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value = {min}
            onChange={handleMin}/>
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.max}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value={max}
            onChange={handleMax}/>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.inputCtrl}>
          <div className="min">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={min}
              onChange={handleMin}/>
          </div>
          <div className="max">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={max}
              onChange={handleMax}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


See my comments, but I'll write this as an answer.
You already have the value in the parent component
Your parent component (by looking at the API of your RangeSlider) must look something along the lines of this:
const minState = useState(0);
const maxState = useState(100);

return (
   <RangerSlider minState={minState} maxState={maxState}/>
)

This means that if you want to "grab" the values in the parent component, due to an event handler for example, you already have them in minState and maxState. Grab them like this:
const minState = useState(0);
const maxState = useState(100);

const handleClick = () => {
   const minValueOfRangeSlider = minState[0];
   const maxValueOfRangeSlider = maxState[0];

   // do something with them
}

return (
   <>
    <RangerSlider minState={minState} maxState={maxState}/>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
   </>
)



the props you are passing as the value should be added in the parent, so what you actually now have are the values you want, besides you can add a handleChange function to the inputs onChange as props for example:
export default function RangeSlider ({min, max, handleChange}: {min: string, max: string, handleChange: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>}) {
return (
   <>
     <input defaultValue={min} name="min" onChange={handleChange}/>
     <input defaultValue={max} name="max" onChange={handleChange}/>
   </>
)

}
and in your parent element you can handle this using this function:
export default function ParentComponent() {

const [state, setState] = useState({
  min: 0,
  max: 0
})

const handleChange = (e) => {
 let { value, name} = e.target;
 setState({...state, [name]:value})
}
return (
  <>
    <RangeSlider min={state.min} max={state.max} handleChange={handleChange} />
  </>

}

use useRef hook to reference the input element and get what you want.
 import React, { useRef } from 'react';
 import styles from './range-slider.module.css';
    
export default function RangeSlider({ minState, maxState }) {
  const [min, setMin] = minState;
  const [max, setMax] = maxState;
  
  // Create refs for min and max inputs
  const minInputRef = useRef(null);
  const maxInputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMin = (e) => {
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setMin(value < parseInt(max) ? value : max);
  };

  const handleMax = (e) => {
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setMax(value > parseInt(min) ? value : min);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.rangeInput}>
        <div className={styles.sliderCtrl}>
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.min}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value={min}
            onChange={handleMin}
            ref={minInputRef} 
          />
          <input 
            type="range" 
            className={`${styles.slider} ${styles.max}`} 
            min="0" 
            max="100"
            value={max}
            onChange={handleMax}
            ref={maxInputRef} 
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.inputCtrl}>
          <div className="min">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={min}
              onChange={handleMin}
              ref={minInputRef} 
            />
          </div>
          <div className="max">
            <input 
              className="val-input" 
              type="number" 
              min="0" 
              max="100"
              value={max}
              onChange={handleMax}
              ref={maxInputRef} 
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


OP is using controlled inputs just fine. useRef is needed when you need to imperatively get the value and you are using uncontrolled inputs. This is wrong.

what are you saying, how is this is an uncontrolled input?
